# How to execute local binaries remotely in Linux?

Tags: ssh, remote, runas

How can I run a program / binary that is local to my machine on a remote computer?

Take a local `perl` script, for example. What I am trying to do is to send this to the remote computer and then invoke it, using `ssh` - something like this:

```
ssh 192.168.1.2 perl - $arg0 $arg1 $arg2 < script.pl
```

How can I do it with a compiled binary?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/241259/how-to-run-a-local-application-on-a-distant-server-with-ssh

Comment: @nKn Yes, it is a duplicate, but the answer is incorrect.